# Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x+\sin (\frac 1 x)} $

Tags: limits

How can I find the following limit without the use of any series or expansion?
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x+\sin (\frac 1 x)} $$
Thanks for help.

Comment: What are your thoughts? How do the various parts of the formula behave when $x$ becomes very small?

Comment: to zero but the way ?

Comment: Note that this function isn't even defined for all $x$ near zero, since $x+\sin\frac{1}{x}=0$ is a clear possibility.

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: for ex: xsin(1\x) when x >0 =0 so the limit are exist and we can use 
-x<xsin(1\x)<x .....because of lim x=lim -x=0 x>0 this lead to lim xsin(1\x)
x>0 =0
is there any way like this to find the solution to my question

Comment: that is what happen with me
the left side is positive and the right side is negative

Comment: this mean that is no standard solution? with out use plot ?

Comment: but to know ...... some time wolfram alpha is wrong like this 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+floor%27%28x%29+from+0+to+2

Comment: DonAntonio's answer is correct.  The quantity is undefined on a sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \neq 0$ and $x_n \to 0$ so the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As bob.sacramento suggests, let $y=1/x$ and then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin(1/x)}
&=\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac1{y+y^2\sin(y)}
\end{align}
$$
There are solutions near every non-zero integer multiple of $\pi$ for $y+y^2\sin(y)=0$. This can be easily verified since $y+y^2\sin(y)\gt0$ when $y=(2k+1/2)\pi$ and $y+y^2\sin(y)\lt0$ when $y=(2k-1/2)\pi$ for $k\ne0$.

For $y=k\pi$, $y+y^2\sin(y)=y$.

Thus, as $y\to\infty$, $\dfrac1{y+y^2\sin(y)}$ gets arbitrarily big and small. Thus, the limit does not exist.

---

**Graphical Support**

Here is a plot of $y+y^2\sin(y)$. It is easy to see why its reciprocal has no limit as $y\to\pm\infty$.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Answer (score 11):

Let $y=1/x$ and take the limit as $y\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 5):

- Note that $x-1 \leq x+ \sin\frac{1}{x} \leq x+1$ and this says that $x^{2}$ increases much much faster than $x+\sin\frac{1}{x}$.  So where should the limit go?

Comment: Very good hint. +1

Comment: for some strange reason, [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+x-%3E0+x%5E2%2F%28x%2Bsin%281%2Fx%29%29) gives the weird result +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, Thank you!

Comment: Good hint, except for the word "increases," since $x\to 0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what word you sugges then? grows ?

Comment: It doesn't grow faster as $x\to 0$, either.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure this hint leads in the right direction. There are values of $x$ arbitrarily close to zero where $x+\sin 1/x=0$. So I think there might not be a limit (even if we exclude those points.)

Comment: I wouldn't believe WA too much, but in this case I get that normal calculation time exceeded...

Comment: if not `Limit[f(x), x->0]` works then [plotting](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E2%2F%28x%2Bsin%281%2Fx%29%29+from+-0.005+to+0.005) gives the general idea. I always use it to verify answer.

Comment: I think I can see what the problem may be in spite of what seemed a good hint...yet it doesn't work (still my +1 shall remain). Apparently Seshadri hinted to the squeeze theorem: $$\frac{x^2}{x+1}\le\frac{x^2}{x+\sin1/x}\le\frac{x^2}{x-1}$$...and the problem is the above inequalities are *false* for $\,0<x<1\,$ , since the leftmost side is positive yet the rightmost one is negative!

Comment: "Obviously"? This word seems to mean for you something different than for me. Anyway, I was trying in my last comment to address the possible flaw in the given hint in this answer.

Comment: And BTW, @Harold: could you please point one point $\,0<x<0.1\,$ for which $\,f(x)>2\,$ , say?

Comment: @DonAntonio oh, I have misread the question. You are right. The limit seems now to be 0.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, @Harold. We all must be careful when using the words "obvious, trivial, simple" , etc.

Comment: Just use Alpha, or some other tool, to find a solution of $\sin(1/x)=-x$ to $20$ decimal places. It is geometrically clear there are such. How perturb the $x$ a very tiny bit.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, I need to sleep, it seems like I was right and just misread it again. The problem is $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\frac{1}{x(1+x\cdot\sin(x))}}$, where the fraction **can** be so big or small how you want. The function can be incredibly big, because $x(1+x\cdot\sin(x))$ can be incredibly small. You asked, why is it obvious to me. It is  because $1+x\cdot\sin(x)$ equals to $0$ with period smaller than $2\pi$. So you can change $x$ a bit ($\Delta x < 2\pi$) and make $1+x\cdot\sin(x)$ close enough to $0$ to make $x(1+x\cdot\sin(x))$ so small as you want.

Comment: That wasn't in fact my question to you, @Harold...and not even whether you were right or wrong: for something to be obvious it must be, imo, that it is something either completely basic and elementary in the theory we're dealing with or else something that follows at once *and almost without thinking deep* from some data or previous work. I don't think neither of these conditions is fulfilled in this case, whether the limit exists or not.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, several folks indicate that WolframAlpha produces strange results and/or should not be trusted too much.  Of course, *no* software should be trusted *too* much but, in this particular case, I think that Alpha's response is perfectly reasonable.  Here's what I see when I enter [limit x^2/(x+sin(1/x)) as x->0](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20x%5E2/%28x%2bsin%281/x%29%29%20as%20x-%3E0):

[image]

Now as Don pointed out, Alpha reports that standard computation time was exceeded.  Nonetheless, the pod of primary interest, namely the "Limit" pod, did complete and simply says "no result found...".   This seems perfectly reasonable, although, "does not exist" or "undefined" could be even better.

As several folks also pointed out, an examination of a graph makes sense as well:

[image]

It now becomes crystal clear what's going on.  For every $\varepsilon>0$ there are $x$ values with $0<|x|<\varepsilon$ and $x+\sin(1/x) = 0$ so that the function is simply not even defined on any entire punctured neighborhood of the origin.

Also, while it is certainly *sufficient* to show that the function is arbitrarily large and small in any neighborhood of the origin, it's not *necessary* to show this; really the problem is much simpler than that.  Again, in order for the limit definition to be satisfied a function must be everywhere defined in some punctured neighborhood of the origin, i.e. some set of the form

$$\{x: 0<|x|<\varepsilon\}$$

and this function isn't - done.  As a similar example, you might consider $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)/\sin(1/x)$.  This function is, in fact, bounded and the same as $y=x$ *except* at an infinite sequence of points that converges to the origin where it is undefined.  A graphical representation that somewhat captures this is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to WA and to [this site](http://rechneronline.de/function-graphs/) , the limit **seems** to exist and be equal to zero, yet in any neighbourhood of zero there is one point (well, in fact infinitely many) where the function's denominator vanishes and, thus, the limit cannot exist in fact. We can try to show this as follows: define

$$f(x)=x+\sin\frac1x$$

We now choose

$$(1)\;\;w_n:=\frac2{(4n+1)\pi}\;,\;n\in\Bbb Z\implies f(w_n)=\frac2{(4n+1)\pi}+1>0$$

$$(2)\;\;z_n:=\frac2{(4n+3)\pi}\;,\;n\in\Bbb Z\implies f(z_n)=\frac2{(4n+3)\pi}-1<0$$

Since clearly $\;w_n\,,\,z_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ and since $\;f\;$ is continuous in the positive reals, we can see that in *any* neighborhood of zero $\,f\,$ changes sign infinite times, and this means our **original**  function isn't defined in infinite points (using the MVT for continuous functions) within any "small" right neighbourhood  of zero. The same can be shown on the negative side of zero.

Comment: What limit "seems to exist and be equal to zero"?  The original??

Comment: Yes @MarkMcClure. In the links you can check it. It is pretty misleading.

Comment: Again - *what* is misleading.  I'm honestly not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: The graph of the function $\,\frac{x^2}{x+\sin 1/x}\,$ is pretty misldeading, as it looks as *if* the limit exists, whereas, as pointed out, it doesn't...

Comment: Oh the *graph*. Hmm... It certainly doesn't look that way to me. Of course, I plotted just *one* graph from -0.1 to 0.1.  In the course of numerical experimentation, one would naturally check the interval from -0.01 to 0.01 and see that the sequence of asymptotes continues. It's just a short step from there to examine the graph of both sides of $sin(1/x)=-x$ from which its geometrically clear that there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Well, it certainly looked that way *to me*...and this is a good lesson for me, and perhaps others, that even in the tiny-tiny neighbourhoods of points one has to be way more careful when dealing with infinitesimal stuff.

Answer (score 1):

note that this function is odd symmetric with respect to $x$. So if we can show that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin{1/x}}=0$, then $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin{1/x}}=0$ as well. We get down to prove this.

Using squeeze theorem, we arrive at:
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x-1}<\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin1/x}<\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x-0}$ and,
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+1}<\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin1/x}<\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+0}$
and 
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+1}=0$ ,also
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x-1}=0$ ,and also
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+0}=0$, so

$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin{1/x}}=0$, and using the symmetric property mentioned above, we get

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{x+\sin{1/x}}=0$